# How to include Blazor to existing project?

Tags: c#, web, asp.net-core, blazor

I have an existing project, and I want to add Blazor to my project, but in all the information available on the internet, I have not found how to do that. All I find is about how to add js to blazor pages.

Comment: What kind of project? That matters a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume that your application want to use client-side Blazor, which would be simplest form to integrate. Also I will assume that you use ASP.NET Core for simplification.

1. You create Blazor client-side application. This application would be completely standalone and in the end would be just WASM code + .NET Dlls interpreted by Mono WASM.
2. In the `ConfigureServices` of your Startup.cs in ASP.NET Core application where you want integrate Blazor add lines below

```
services.AddResponseCompression(opts =>
{
    opts.MimeTypes = ResponseCompressionDefaults.MimeTypes.Concat(new[] { "application/octet-stream" });
});
```

See https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Components/Blazor/Templates/src/content/BlazorHosted-CSharp/BlazorHosted-CSharp.Server/Startup.cs#L18-L22

3. In the `Configure` of your Startup.cs in ASP.NET Core application where you want integrate Blazor add lines below

```
app.UseBlazor<BlazorAppClient.Startup>();
```

where `BlazorAppClient.Startup` is Startup class of your Blazor standalone application which you create earlier.
See https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Components/Blazor/Templates/src/content/BlazorHosted-CSharp/BlazorHosted-CSharp.Server/Startup.cs#L43

All of that under assumption that you use latest .NET Core 3 Preview 5 bits.